# NSOuputStream writing multiple times

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, sockets

I'm trying to use the NSStream objects to open and then write and read on a socket but i have a problem.

I don't know how to write on the socket, after i have opened it.

Here is how i have done

1) first openning the socket :

```
 NSURL *website = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]; 
        if (!website) { 
            NSLog(@"%@ is not a valid URL"); 
            return; 
        } 
        NSHost *host = [NSHost hostWithName:urlStr]; 
        // iStream and oStream are instance variables 
        [NSStream getStreamsToHost:host port:6667 inputStream:&iStream 
                      outputStream:&oStream]; 
        [iStream retain]; 
        [oStream retain]; 
        [iStream setDelegate:self]; 
        [oStream setDelegate:self]; 
        [iStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] 
                           forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode]; 
        [oStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] 
                           forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode]; 
        [iStream open]; 
        [oStream open];
```

2) Set the loop :

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent
{
    NSString *io;

    if (theStream == iStream) io = @">>";
    else io = @"<<";
    NSLog(@"stream : %@",theStream);

    NSString *event;
    switch (streamEvent)
    {
        case NSStreamEventNone:
            event = @"NSStreamEventNone";
            break;
        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            event = @"NSStreamEventOpenCompleted";
            break;
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:{
            event = @"NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailables";
            if (theStream == iStream)
            {
                if(!_data) { 
                    _data = [[NSMutableData data] retain]; 
                } 
                uint8_t buf[1024]; 
                unsigned int len = 0; 
                len = [iStream read:buf maxLength:1024]; 
                NSLog(@"Lenght data read : %d", len);
                if(len) { 
                    NSData * dataReceived= [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s\n", (char *)buf] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                    NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataReceived encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                    NSLog(@"Received _data: \"%@\"\n",s);



                } else { 
                    NSLog(@"nothing to read!"); 
                } 
            }else {
                NSLog(@"Not the good stream");
            }

            break;
        }

        case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:{
            event = @"NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable";
            if (theStream == oStream )
            {
                if(isConnexionCommandSent == NO){
                    [self sendCommand:@"My connection command"];    
                    isConnexionCommandSent = YES;
                }

            }

            break;
        }

        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
            event = @"NSStreamEventErrorOccurred";
            NSError *theError = [theStream streamError]; 
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[theError localizedDescription]
                                                           delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
            break;
        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
            event = @"NSStreamEventEndEncountered";

            break;
        default:
            event = @"** Unknown";
    }

    NSLog(@"%@ : %@", io, event);
}
```

3) then i have a function that is called when I touch a button

```
- (IBAction)join:(id)sender{
    if([oStream hasSpaceAvailable]){
        NSLog(@"iStream Status : %d",[iStream streamStatus]);
        NSLog(@"oStream Status : %d",[oStream streamStatus]);
        [self sendCommand:@"join"];

    }else{
        NSLog(@"Error command can't be sent");      
    }
}

-(void) sendCommand:(NSString *) command{
    NSLog(@"space : %d",[oStream hasSpaceAvailable]);
    if ([oStream hasSpaceAvailable])
    {
        NSLog(@"Command writen : %s\n",[command cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
        NSInteger i=[oStream write:(const uint8_t *)[command cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] maxLength:(NSInteger)[command lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
        if (i<0)
        {
            NSLog(@"erreur lors de l'envoi, status:%i, erreur:%@", [oStream streamStatus], [oStream streamError]);
        }
        isReadyToSend = NO;
    }

    else
    {
        NSLog(@"impossible d'envoyer, status:%i, erreur:%@", [oStream streamStatus], [oStream streamError]);
    }
}
```

But the problem is that when the function join is called, everything goes fine, but the server receives nothing ...

On

```
NSInteger i=[oStream write:(const uint8_t *)[command cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] maxLength:(NSInteger)[command lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
```

i is > 0, so i assume that the writing went well, but on the server nothing is received ... i don't know why ...

Can you help me?

Comment: Does the '[self sendCommand:@"My connection command"];' succeed? 

If the 'write' succeeds, it means client tcp stack is now trying to deliver those bytes. But if the tcp connection has died, it won't be delivered. Are you sure the data is not received, how did you verify this?

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Ptitaw see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356857/how-do-i-know-if-my-client-ios-app-is-connected-to-the-server). I believe there you might find your answer and an easier way to connect and get access automatically to all events (reading, writing, etc..)
Hope I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

A Very very late answer, however, it might be helpful to someone having similar issue.

I think it may be due to data encoding mechanism. Your server might be using UTF-8 encoding and you are sending your data using NSASCIIStringEncoding. Try this:

```
NSInteger i=[oStream write:(const uint8_t *)[command cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] maxLength:(NSInteger)[command lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```