# How do i know if my client iOS app is connected to the server?

Tags: cocoa-touch, networking, client-server, cfnetwork

I press the button to connect to the server (TCP), but i don't know whether it connected or not..
Here is that part of the code:

`[self connectToServerUsingCFStream:msg portNo:50000];`

```
    if(readStream && writeStream)
    {
        NSString *newText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Connected!! :)"]; 
        statusText.text = newText;
        [newText release];
        pingButton.hidden = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *newText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Connection unsuccessful :("]; 
        statusText.text = newText;
        [newText release];
    }
```

I always get the "Connected!! :)" even if the server is offline :s

Comment: What kind of server? HTTP? FTP? …? or something over TCP/IP?

Comment: If your iPhone starts burning or explodes when you press the button, its most likely not connected. However, a not burning iPhone could also indicate that its underwater.

Comment: and provide code. I lost my Crytsal Ball.

Comment: @JustSid ahah. @vikingosegundo deves perceber isto não? já postei mais info no outro comment..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution for people following the connection method:

```
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, 
                                   (CFStringRef) urlStr, 
                                   portNo, 
                                   &readStream, 
                                   &writeStream);

if (readStream && writeStream) 
{
    CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream, 
                            kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket, 
                            kCFBooleanTrue);
    CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream, 
                             kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket, 
                             kCFBooleanTrue);

    iStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
    [iStream retain];
    [iStream setDelegate:self];
    [iStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] 
                       forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [iStream open];

    oStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
    [oStream retain];
    [oStream setDelegate:self];
    [oStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] 
                       forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [oStream open];         
}
```

is using the

`-(void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent`

like this:

```
-(void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent
{
NSString *io;
if (theStream == iStream) io = @">>";
else io = @"<<";

NSString *event;
switch (streamEvent)
{
    case NSStreamEventNone:
        event = @"NSStreamEventNone";
        statusText.text =  @"Can not connect to the host!";
        break;

    case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
        event = @"NSStreamEventOpenCompleted";
        pingButton.hidden = NO;
        statusText.text = @"Connected";
        break;

    case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
        event = @"NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable";
        if (theStream == iStream)
        {
            //read data
            uint8_t buffer[1024];
            int len;
            while ([iStream hasBytesAvailable])
            {
                len = [iStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                if (len > 0)
                {
                    NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
                    NSData *theData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len];
                    if (nil != output)
                    {
                        //do something with data
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        break;

    case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:
        event = @"NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable";
        if (theStream == oStream)
        {
            //send data
            uint8_t buffer[11] = "I send this";             
            int len;

            len = [oStream write:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
            if (len > 0)
            {
                NSLog(@"Command send");
                [oStream close];
            }
        }

        break;

    case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
        event = @"NSStreamEventErrorOccurred";
        statusText.text = @"Can not connect to the host!";
        pingButton.hidden = YES;
        break;

    case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
        event = @"NSStreamEventEndEncountered";
        statusText.text = @"Connection closed by the server.";
        pingButton.hidden = YES;
        [theStream close];
        [theStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [theStream release];
        theStream = nil;
        break;

    default:
        event = @"** Unknown";
}

NSLog(@"%@ : %@", io, event);
}
```

(for all I know!) The credits go to **deksa** from [this post](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=858587) (though i don't know who was the creator, because i've seen this some times on the web, including here o SO). This code was slightly modified by me (pingButton, statusText), if you want the original one go to the link previously mentioned.

The [Apple Developer Site](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has some info on this as well.

Like i've said, I had seen some stuff looking like this on the web, but now i understand that everything that happens after you connect is "automatic"; for instance, if the server is on hold with a `read()`, the `case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:` will be called automatically, and all the code in there will be run.

Now I consider this question answered.

Answer (score 1):

Although you did not provide enough informations, I'd suggest to use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) for HTTP, and [AsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) for TCP and UDP. If an connection was established, callback methods will be triggered,

I have to say, that my experiences with CFNetwork are very limited, but for me it seems, as if you are just testing, if stream objects exists (`if(readStream && writeStream)`).
A quick look at [CFNetwork Programming Guide: Working with Read Streams](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/CFStreamTasks/CFStreamTasks.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001132-CH6-SW1) tells me, that you have to open it with `CFReadStreamOpen()`, this function will return an boolean, if it really did open the stream.

```
if (!CFReadStreamOpen(myReadStream)) {
    CFStreamError myErr = CFReadStreamGetError(myReadStream);
    // An error has occurred.
        if (myErr.domain == kCFStreamErrorDomainPOSIX) {
        // Interpret myErr.error as a UNIX errno.
        } else if (myErr.domain == kCFStreamErrorDomainMacOSStatus) {
        // Interpret myErr.error as a MacOS error code.
            OSStatus macError = (OSStatus)myErr.error;
        // Check other error domains.
    }
}
```

**BTW:**
instead of

```
NSString *newText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Connected!! :)"]; 
statusText.text = newText;
[newText release];
```

you just can write `statusText.text = @"Connected!! :)";`

Comment: oh right lol so the connection is TCP and i connected with [self connectToServerUsingCFStream:msg portNo:50000];. Those callback methods, that's what i want to know lol (how do i use the tag 'code' btw?)

Comment: ups! its actually `CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost` that i use to connect to the server.

Comment: hum.. i looked around and maybe [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/NetworkStreams.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002277-BCIDFCDI) help (i had a code similar to this written by someone else but didnt work..): _If the socket connection fails, then one or both of the requested CFReadStreamRef and CFWriteStreamRef objects are NULL._ I'm gonna try it out now.

Comment: I never succeeded in using the CFNetwork stuff. And I tried… AsyncSocket is a thin layer around CFNetwork*, that will give you simple to use classes and callback methods to make your life much easier. And when I say much, I mean MUUUCH.

Comment: hum.. ok @vikingosegundo, i've been avoiding it, but im gonna check it out. I'll post some feedback on it. thks

Comment: IMHO there is no disadvantage to use those kind of third party codes: I think, thousands of developers use ASIHTTPRequest and AsyncSocket. So it is very likely, that bugs will be identified, filed and removed. Furthermore it provides you just with functionality you otherwise would have to write your own — for thousands of projects that would made hundred of thousands development hours — what a waste of recourses.

Comment: am i missing something, or there's no easy example in the documentation? :s

Comment: basically you instanciate a asyncsocket, set its delegate to a controller conforming to its delegate and implement the receiving methods like `- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sender didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag`. Here is the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/wiki/Reference_AsyncSocket) and here [some explaining blogpost](http://www.macresearch.org/cocoa-scientists-part-xxix-message)

Comment: see.. im a total noob in the iOS world :s so i still dont get the delegate thing and when and where i have to put it, etc.. so its a bit difficult this AsyncSocket for me. My code works well and i can receive and send data in perfect conditions. The problem is when the server is offline and i don't have any signal that shows the program that a connection hasn't been made.

Comment: The delegate pattern is essential in the cocoa world. U need it for everything. you should make clear you understand it. but there are plenty of explanations here on SO and in the docs of apple.

Comment: yeah, i've read an entire book, but they have simple and well explained examples only... when it comes to write our own code, that's a totally different story. anyway the code i would like to have should be something like this:
`- (BOOL)isConnected
{
    if(/*SOMETHING*/)
        return YES; 
    else
        return NO;
}`

Comment: `if(readStream && writeStream)`this seems to be the condition used everywhere,and makes sense cuz after checking the method's info i see that one, or both of these streams become NULL if a connection isn't made. that simply doesn't happen to me.. the condition is fulfilled even if its not connected. arghh :x (and sorry for not going with AsyncSocket but i have the whole code working, except this part!)

Comment: lol thks for the NSString tip ;) about the edit.. hu didn't work: in the server it says that i connected, but one the client goes to that if and says that it didn't connect (my printf, obviously).